# Python-like "pack" and "unpack" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to decode a message received in this form `b'\r\x01\x00\x00\x00'` from a device. The only way to do this is to convert a Python function to Javascript, I've tried to do this but the unpacking operation doesn't work like in Python, obviously.

This is the python code:

```
def DecodeData(self, data):
    try:
        n = struct.unpack('b',bytes(data[0:1]))[0]
        print(n)
        id , type, m = self._DecodeId(n)
        value = struct.unpack(type, bytes(data[1:]))[0]/m
        return (id, value)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

I have to run the Javascript code in Datacake Payload-Decoder section and the result should be `('CIN_3', 1.0)`, or something like that.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892053/how-to-unpack-binary-in-javascript

Comment: Are you saying that a string "b'\r\x01\x00\x00\x00'" somehow translates to "('CIN_3', 1.0)"? Can you be *exact* about the input format? Does it start with a literal "b" and then a quote?

Comment: Yes, the message always starts with a b and then a quote.

Comment: @georg there is a way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605108/pack-unpack-functions-for-node-js